# Stuck at os.rename()

Tags: php, python, html

i am ubuntu user.. i have a command in php that exec a python file.. the python file is set to executable.. so, my php command is:-

```
 shell_exec("try.py");
```

the python file is located at desktop.. but the php file is located in www folder..

```
 /var/www/try.php
```

in the try.py, i have a code to rename a file on the desktop as follow:-

```
 print "enter"
 os.rename("a.txt", "b.txt")
 print "exit"
```

so, the try.py and a.txt are in desktop..

my problem is, when i execute the php file, it shows the "enter" only but not with the "exit".. so i guess it cannot execute the os.rename maybe because of the root privilege or anything that i dont know.. i have tried some solutions to disable password for sudo but still i didnt show the "exit".

but, if i execute the try.py directly by double click it on the desktop and execute it, the command can be done and the output shows:-

```
enter
exit
```

so, anyone knows how to execute it using php?

Comment: Maybe instead of trying `os.rename` for testing purposes try something like `print "%s"%os.listdir(os.getcwd())` and see if it exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, i got the solution..

to be able to rename the file in desktop using os.rename, we need to edit some of the configurations in sudoers..

it involved some steps in visudo and also the php script..

in visudo (using command "sudo visudo" in terminal:)-

```
#user privilege specification
root All=(ALL:ALL) ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL //use your username.. mine is ubuntu
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL //the place where i put the php file
```

in php file:-

```
<?php
$output = exec("sudo python /home/ubuntu/Desktop/[filename.py]");
?>
```

for python file is just the same..

```
os.rename("a.txt", "b.txt")
```

ok.. that is the solution.. now i can run the python script which it will change the name of a file in desktop from php..

Thank you for all the comments and suggestion for the solutions.. =))

Answer (score 1):

You can directly rename files in `php` using the [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

```
rename($oldname, $newname);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are doing `os.rename("a.txt", "b.txt")` it is looking for `a.txt` in the directory from where the application is running (so it is looking for `a.txt` in `/var/www/`.

You should give both `a.txt` and `b.txt` the full path:

```
os.rename('/home/user/Desktop/a.txt', '/home/user/Desktop/b.txt')
```

You will also have to make sure that `www-data` (or whatever user is running Apache) can write to the Desktop directory; however **from a security perspective this is a very bad idea** - any script running on the server can read the contents of your desktop (and even delete the files).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
my_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

That will equate to the directory try.py is actually in.

Then you can execute:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(my_dir, 'a.txt'), os.path.join(my_dir, 'b.txt'))
```

As mentioned above, this isn't necessarily a great idea from a security PoV though, since you have to grant write permissions to the php script.

I also usually put the my_dir code in an `if sys.argv[0]:` so that I can still debug from python REPL:

```
if sys.argv[0]:
    # running as executable
    my_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
else:
    # imported into interpreter
    my_dir = '.'
```

That way I can still import the module into REPL to debug it, as long as I'm in the same directory as the file in question.